# Netty 5.0.0Alpha1 SSLHandler crashing after one request

Tags: java, ssl, netty

I am struggling with an issue with Netty 5.0.0Alpha1. Currently I am working on upgrade of one of our APIs to use SSL. When I setup everything as shown in examples, the server processes one request and crashes. Basically I am able to get untrusted certificate warning on firefox and the server resets connection on every single subsequent request. And no further helpful information in logs. I have set io.netty to DEBUG level.

Here are code samples of my server initialization:

**Bootstrap:**

```
String cfgKsLocation = ; // .....
String cfgKsPassword = ; // .....

KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
keystore.load(new FileInputStream(new File(cfgKsLocation)), cfgKsPassword.toCharArray());

KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
kmf.init(keystore, cfgKsPassword.toCharArray());

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

this.sslEngine = sslContext.createSSLEngine();
this.sslEngine.setUseClientMode(false);

EventLoopGroup nettyBossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
EventLoopGroup nettyWorkerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(2);
try {
      ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
      bootstrap.group(nettyBossGroup, nettyWorkerGroup);
      bootstrap.channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class);
      bootstrap.childHandler(new ApiChannelInitializer());
      bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, cfgServerBacklog);
      bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
      Channel channel = bootstrap.bind(cfgServerIpAddress, cfgServerPort).sync().channel();
      channel.closeFuture().sync();
} finally {
      nettyBossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
      nettyWorkerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
}
```

**ApiChannelInitializer:**

```
private class ApiChannelInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel c) throws Exception {
        c.pipeline().addLast(new SslHandler(ApiServer.this.sslEngine));
        c.pipeline().addLast(new HttpRequestDecoder());
        c.pipeline().addLast(new HttpResponseEncoder());
        c.pipeline().addLast(new HttpContentCompressor());
        c.pipeline().addLast(new ApiChannelInboundHandler());
    }

}
```

**What I have tried so far:**

- Removing arguments from EventLoopGroup constructions
- Using different certificate which works fine with Java SecureSocketServer
- Changing to netty version 4.0.X
- Adding DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder to pipline after SslHandler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after several hour struggle this solved my problem. The problem was that ssl alerts were crashing the SSLEngine inside SSLHandler. If there is only one SSLHandler attached at the beginning of the pipeline and it's SSLEngine crashes, the SSLHandler is no longer able to process SSL/TLS connection.

So I have added this override to my inbound channel handler:

```
    @Override
    public void channelRegistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        SSLEngine sslEngine = ApiServer.this.sslContext.createSSLEngine();
        sslEngine.setNeedClientAuth(false);
        sslEngine.setUseClientMode(false);
        SslHandler sslHandler = new SslHandler(sslEngine);
        ctx.pipeline().addFirst(sslHandler);
    }
```